# Как написать не число в программе int(input())

Tags: python

Если написать
`int(input())`
И если в консоль вписать не число то выйдет ошибка как написать код чтобы он при введении не числа (примечание: исправлено @Sergey) в консоль не выдавал ошибку или хотя бы удалял за собой буквы без удаления `int(input())`

Comment: `как написать код чтобы он при введении числа в консоль не выдавал ошибку` - этот код не будет выдавать ошибку при введении числа. Вы противоречите себе же. Уточните вопрос кнопкой "править".

Comment: Вопрос конкретизирован, суть ясна. Я исправил текст вопроса Ирагима, учитывая принятие им моего ответа (= я правильно его понял). В вопросе просто одно "не" было пропущено - автор хочет слова вместо чисел позволять иногда писать без остановки программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не хотите остановки программы при введении нечислового значения, то самым правильным будет обработка исключений. Но подозреваю, что вы еще до этого не дошли в изучении Python и это будет сложно. Поэтому рекомендую разделить `int(input())` на две части и действовать  так (будет запрашивать ввод программа, пока не окажутся только цифры после ввода):

```
integer = False
while not integer:
    str_test = input()
    if str_test.isdigit():
        final = int(str_test)
        integer = True
print (final)
```